# What is the best way to add user points to existing users

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I have a dev and prod versions of my D7 site. On dev I developed some functionality based on `User Points` module and plan to roll out it on prod. But it requires some initial number of user points for every user.

What is the best way to add user points to existing users: SQL query, [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) etc?

Comment: There's no "best" way, only different ways. Yes you can do it with an SQL query, not sure how you'd do it with rules, or you could probably set something up with [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). Which one is best for you depends on what you already know and how quickly you pick up new things. Have a go, and if you get _stuck_, ask a more specific question and you'll surely get a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method here is to use the Userpoints API and execute a code snippet that will add the points for you. You can reference the [userpoints API here](https://www.drupal.org/node/206558). You can do something like this...

```
$initial_value = 10;
//@TODO: Build a list of all $uids in an array
foreach($uids as $uid) { =
  userpoints_userpointsapi(array(
    'uid' => $uid,
    'points' => $initial_value,
    'operation' => "Add Initial User Point Value",
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [User Points Contributed modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) is a possible alternative to consider. I. e. submodule **userpoints_retroactive**. Excerpt from that project page:

> Award users points for their nodes, comments and votes that they have created so far, before userpoints was enabled on the site.

However, the [port of this module to D7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1963542) still **needs work**. Maybe you can/want to somehow contriute to the finishing touch of that issue?

Another approach to consider: create a rule with specs like so:

- **Event** = a user logging in
- **Condition** like "if user points is 0"
- **Action** to set the initial number of user points.

Haven't actually created such rule (yet), but pretty sure that's fairly easy to do.

PS: there is also [Berdir's Api documentation](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints_contrib-7.x-1.x!userpoints_retroactive!userpoints_retroactive.module/7-1) about this submodule ... (maybe that helps somehow).